# Altering the range of positional computation systems

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, permutations, logarithms, computational-mathematics

From Vladimir Zorich Analysis I:

> A number $x$ is represented on a computer as $$x=\pm
>  q^{p}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{a_n}{q_n}$$
>
> where $p$ is the order of $x$ and $M=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{a_n}{q_n}$ is
>   the mantissa of the number $x$ ($\frac{1}{q} \leq M < 1)$.
>
> Now a computer works only with a certain range of numbers: for $q=2$
>   usually $\left| p \right| \leq 64$ and $k =35$. Evaluate this range in
>   the decimal system.

**Definition**:

My textbook by the principle of Archimedes and simple algebraic inequality manipulations shows (in a less formal manner) that there exists rational approximation $r_n$ of any $x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, such that:

$$r_n = {a_p}{q^p}+...+a_{p-n}q^{p-n}$$

where $q^{p-m}$ for $m \in \{0, 1, ...,n\}$, $q \in \mathbb{R}^{+}/\{0\}$ and $a_{p-m}$ for $m \in \{0, 1, ...,n\}$. Usually, $p$ is called an order of $x$ in the base $q$.

For example, when $q=10$,

$$123.45=1 \times 10^2 + 2 \times 10^1 + 3 \times 10^0 + 4 \times 10^{-1} + 5 \times 10^{-5}$$

The term "mantissa" mentioned above is slightly misleading (as often quoted by Donald Knuth), but in this case it obviously represents a significand.

**My Attempt**:

I'm unable to understand explicitly the purpose of the question, but I've tried simplifying the question by initially omitting significand part (or mantissa part):

Let $r_n = {a_p}{q^p}+...+a_{p-n}q^{p-n}$ be an approximation for any integer $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, let $A=\{{a_p},...,a_{p-n}\}$ and $O = \{\sigma_1, ... , \sigma_n\}$ be a set of all permutations of $A$, such that $\sigma_{i} : A \rightarrow A$. Usually on the computers, if $q=2$, the "maximum" order of $O$ for integral part is $q^{64}$, what is the "maximum" order of $O$ if $q=10$?

The answer to the question I've proposed is $10^{\log_{10}{(2^{64})}} \approx 10^{19.3}$, and perhaps the same logic could be applied to the significand part of $x$ if it was a rational number (instead of integer, as assumed in my question). I think this seems reasonable, since I've evaluated the ranges in different bases by simply using the logarithmic equation.

Did I understand the task properly? My answer seems too straightforward to be valid, do I have to use lower-order logic to prove relation between different ranges of different basis?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are meant to set $q=10.$

I think the intention rather is to say, given that
$$x=\pm q^p\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{a_n}{q_n}$$
where $q=2$, $\lvert p \rvert \leq 64$, and $k =35$,
what is the largest possible value of $x$?
The answer should be evaluated exactly as written above (in particular,
$q=2\neq 10$), but use decimal notation when showing the result.

It might also be desired for you to write the smallest possible non-zero value of $x,$ again evaluating it exactly as written in the formula but showing the answer in decimal notation.

That said, I wonder what kind of computers Prof. Zorich works with on which
$\lvert p \rvert \leq 64$ and $k =35$.
Those parameters seem to imply a $42$-bit word.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I too got curious about limitations presented in the textbook - but then again it was originally published in 1965. As for the choice of $x$, wouldn't $x$ be $2^{64} + M$ where $M = \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} x$ at the floating point precision of $35$? Or should I construct such "upper bound" using Archimedes principle (if possible)?

Comment: For $M$, consider the case when $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_{35}=1.$ If that's what you mean by "$\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} x$ at the floating point precision of $35$", you're already on the right path.

Comment: For $M$, I implied $a_1=a_2=...=a_35=9$ (therefore my limit notation wasn't entirely accurate). I assume I'm missing something...

Comment: Remember, $q=2\neq 10.$ The only digits that make sense for $a_i$ are either $0$ or $1.$ The sum is $\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots+\frac1{2^{35}}.$

Comment: I think now I can understand! I was slightly baffled by the world "decimal" due to its original definition. Thank you very much for the help!